# Calling inputs to myProgram from different directories

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

`myProgram` takes three files as inputs, like so:

```
$ myProgram inputA inputB inputC
```

And say these inputs themselves reside in their own respective directories w/ some additional files:

```
directoryA
  inputA
  inputA_helperfile1
  inputA_helperfile2
directoryB
  inputB
  inputB_helperfile1
  inputB_helperfile2
directoryC
  inputC
  inputC_helperfile1
  inputC_helperfile2
```

`myProgram` will not run properly unless **all three inputs as well as these additional files** (dependencies? Is that the right term?) are in the same directory. But I do not want to put all these files into the same directory in order to execute `myProgram`. Is there a workaround for this scenario?

I am very new to bash (and programming/scripting in general), so please forgive me if this is a trivial question! (It is non-trivial to me, and I was unable to find an adequate answer by Googling for it.)

Comment: Sounds like you either want to a) take the directory as the argument, or b) pass the full path.  What do you currently do if the files `foo/inputA` and `bar/inputA` exist?  Do you want to locate each and process both?  If so, require the caller to pass them both.

Comment: @WilliamPursell it was actually more of a pass the full path issue (which did work out in the end). Thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to propose a good solution if you would explain what exactly `myProgram` is. Did you implement it?
Is it documented that it requires all files to be in one directory?
What happens if you call your program like this?

```
myProgram directoryA/inputA directoryB/inputB directoryC/inputC
```

If `myProgram`  requires that all files are in the same directory, you could write a script that creates a temporary directory, changes the working directory into this temporary directory, copies all files there, executes `myProgram inputA inputB inputC`, leaves the temporary directory and removes it including all contents.

Instead of copying the files you can also create symbolic links in the temporary directory if your file system allows this.

You probably would implement your script to be called like this

```
myScript directoryA/inputA directoryB/inputB directoryC/inputC
```

You could use `dirname` and `find` to list all files from `directory[ABC]` if your program needs all files that reside in these directories. Otherwise you have to specify how to find out which of all the files are `inputA_helperfile1` etc.

You may have to handle duplicate file names. If e.g. `inputA_helperfile1` and `inputB_helperfile1` would actually be the same file names with different content you cannot copy both files into the same directory.